# How to set the default value of a dropdown menu in Django?

Tags: django, html, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, django-forms

Currently, I have the following 2 Drop-Down menus to display the years and weeks but I want to display the current year and current week, respectively, inside of these menus.

**Django form**

```
from django import forms

class DropDownMenuForm(forms.Form):
    week = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,x) for x in range (1,53)])
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,x) for x in range (2016,2021)])
```

**Template to display the menus**

```
<form id="search_dates" method="POST" action="{{ action }}"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div style="display:inline-block">
            <h6>Select year</h6>
                <select name="select_year">
                    <option value={{form.year}}></option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block">
            <h6>Select week</h6>
            <select name="select_week">
                <option value={{form.week}}></option>
            </select>
        </div>
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Display the current week and year**

```
from datetime import date
date.today().isocalendar()[1]
date.today().year
```

How can I connect the *Display the current week and year code* with the template, so I can see the current year and week selected in the dropdown menus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial) value for form field:

```
from datetime import date
from django import forms

class DropDownMenuForm(forms.Form):
    week = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,x) for x in range (1,53)], initial=date.today().isocalendar()[1])
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,x) for x in range (2016,2021)], initial=date.today().year)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default using the initial="" attribute. See the example below from the Django Docs

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial)

```
from django import forms
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(initial='Your name')
    url = forms.URLField(initial='http://')
    comment = forms.CharField()
f = CommentForm(auto_id=False)
print(f)
<tr><th>Name:</th><td><input type="text" name="name" value="Your name" required /></td></tr>
<tr><th>Url:</th><td><input type="url" name="url" value="http://" required /></td></tr>
<tr><th>Comment:</th><td><input type="text" name="comment" required />
</td></tr>
```